# SQL - Complex query using foreign keys

Tags: sql

So, I am totally new to SQL, but the book I have from the courses I take is useless and I am trying to do a project for said course. Internet did not help me all that much (I do not know where to start exactly), so I want to ask for both links to good tutorials to check out as well as help with a very specific piece of query.

If anything I say is not clear enough, please ask me to explain! :)

Suppose two tables `sale` and `p_sale` in a database called `jewel_store`.

`sale` contains two columns: `sale_CODE` and `sale_date`

`p_sale` contains `sale_CODE` which references the above `sale_ID`, `p_ID`, `p_sl_quantity` and 
`p_sl_value`

`sale_CODE` is the primary key of `sale` and `sale_CODE,p_ID` is the primary key of `p_sale`

For the time being `p_ID` is not of much use so just ignore it for the most part.

`p_sl_quantity`is `int` and `p_sl_value` is `double(8,2)`. The first one is the quantity of the product bought and the second one is the value **PER UNIT** of the product.

As it probably is obvious a `sale_CODE` can be linked to a multitude of entries in the `p_sale` table (example for sale_CODE 1, I have 2 entries on p_sale).

All this is based on what I was given from the task and is correctly implemented and has some example values in.

What I now have to do is find the total income from sales in a specific month. My initial approach was to start structuring everything step by step so I have come to a point that looks like the follows:

`SELECT
    SUM(p_sl_value * p_sl_quantity) AS sales_monthly_income,
    p_sale.sale_CODE
FROM jewel_store.p_sale
GROUP BY p_sale.sale_CODE`

This is probably half way through as I can get the total money a sale generated for the store. So my next step was to use this query and SELECT from it. I messed it up a couple of times already and I am scratching my head now. What I did was like this:

```
SELECT
    SUM(sales_monthly_income),
    sales_monthly_income,
    EXTRACT(MONTH FROM jewel_store.sale.sale_date) AS sales_month
FROM (
SELECT
    SUM(p_sl_value * p_sl_quantity) AS sales_monthly_income,
    sale_CODE
FROM jewel_store.p_sale
GROUP BY sale_CODE
) as code_income, jewel_store.sale
GROUP BY sales_month
```

First off, I only need to print the `total_montly_income` and the `month` columns in my final form, but I used this to clarify that everything went wrong in there. I think I need to somehow use the foreign key that references the other table, but my book is totally useless in helping me out. I would like someone to explain why this is wrong and what the right one would be and **please point me to a good pdf, site or anything to learn how to do this kind of stuff**. (I have checked W3SCHOOLS, it is good for the basics, but not for too advanced stuff)

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I'd [recommend to **not** go to W3Schools](http://www.w3fools.com/) ....

Comment: I know of that, but for SQL things seem to be ok there, plus I can really use the List formatting of the page, helps a lot! Still, I need some better resources than W3SCHOOLS! ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the top of my head this could be it, group by month the sum of value times quantity.

```
SELECT
    SUM(p.p_sl_value * p.p_sl_quantity) AS sales_monthly_income,
    month(s.sale_date)
FROM p_sale p
inner join sale s on s.sale_code = p.sale_code
GROUP BY MONTH(s.sale_date)
```

Comment: Works like a charm! Still looking for some reference material on how to use foreign keys, but I think I understand a little bit more now! Thanks a lot!